# How do I set a Line or Box in front of the image?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, line

I've insert image in crystal report by following step,
In the Section Expert for the section containing the image, check
Underlay Following Sections.
but, when some line or box created, the image still in front of them.
i can't set Line or Box in front of the image

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the most elegant solution to the problem but you can use a textbox, and fill it with underscores. It will give the illusion of a line and since it will show above the image.

**Note:** It may not look that good in the report preview (it sometimes shows as separated dashes), but when you actually run it, export it to pdf or print it, it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

You **should** be able to right click on the image and choose Move/To Back. This will move the image to the back of the Z order.

(should is in bold because this should work, but it doesn't) :)

Edit:
I realize that now that my original answer on this is incorrect. Here is a similar question for reference with some other ideas.

[How to draw a line above a picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102124/how-to-draw-a-line-in-picture)

Answer (score 1):

You could insert an empty text field and give it a border on the top side. 
In that case you simulate a line.

By moving your field to the front (or your image to the back) this 'line' will always be in front of the image.